# NetSuite Record Creation Event

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

**How can I change a field on a form when it is initially created, but not when it is later edited?** I'm currently using a Client script and coding for this with the pageInit function, but I need to allow my users to manually change the field after it is initially created without the script overriding their changes.

Let me know if more details are needed for what I am exactly trying to accomplish.

Comment: Is this done using the type parameter? Like `function pageInit(type){if(type == 'create'){//dostuff}}`

Comment: Looks like this works, making this an answer to my own question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I mentioned in a comment above, I figured this out. Using the type parameter of the pageInit function, I can make events fire on page edit or page creation like this:

```
function pageInit(type){if(type == 'create'){//do stuff}else{//do other stuff}}
```

Comment: Glad you found your own answer! FWIW if you need to do similar work on the server-side, before the page gets sent to the user's browser, you can also use the `Before Load` event on a *User Event* script; that handler gets passed a similar `type` parameter.

Comment: Thank you! I was kinda kicking myself when I found the answer, because I've passed "entity" as a parameter before, but never tried passing "type" as a parameter until I found the info in the Help Center.